# crossdomain issue with Flex Application

Tags: apache-flex, cross-domain, crossdomain.xml

I have a flex application that has a button that calls a URL.
The source of the URL is a location on the same Apache web server as the Flex application.

I have dumped a crossdomain file under webapps and also under ROOT folder:

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

However, my Flex application is still returning a 2048 error, which I understand to be an issue relating to not having the cross-domain file setup correctly.

Please see this short [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/F7HJ7ElKI) for more info.

In the long run, I need the tool to be able to open any publically accessible file from several different web servers.

Comment: First off, use Flash Player Debug, and use the debugging to post the full error message, not just the error number.  Second, why are you using an absolute path to get your txt file? And finally, show some code as we have no idea how you're trying to access said file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need the port?  Looks like you're on 8080 -

```
<cross-domain-policy>
<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="80,443,8080"/>
<site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="all"/>
<allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Thanks!  I have added that change, and copied the same crossdomain.xml to both the webapps folder, the ROOT folder, and also the folder that the txt file is sitting in.  Rebooted apache and deleted browser cache = still same error.

Comment: It seems strange that your faultCode does not reference a channel security error.  Is the endpoint for that amf service mapped elsewhere?  I'd check content MIME type for that text file, too.